# iOS/Android does keep linking requires an HTTP server

Tags: android, ios

I want to let users click on a link on an email or SMS message, and then open the app and deep link into a specific page/ViewController.

I know there is a more general implementation, when user browse your website with a mobile web browser, and if your app is installed, launch your app instead of keep browsing it in the web browser.

I was wondering if deep linking itself can be done without setting up a server?

In iOS parlance, I want to register a custom URI scheme, and when user taps on a link via the custom URI scheme in a mobile email client or SMS message app, open our app, and get some payload into it as well so I can deep link into a specific ViewController.

(Sorry I don't know Android well, though I do need it on Android as well. I'm actually working with Cordova.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**, deep linking on Android does not require an http server

https://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html

It works the same way - a custom URI scheme

> To enable Google to crawl your app content and allow users to enter your app from search results, you must add intent filters for the relevant activities in your app manifest. These intent filters allow deep linking to the content in any of your activities. For example, the user might click on a deep link to view a page within a shopping app that describes a product offering that the user is searching fo

Comment: Do you happen to know iOS? I suspect it is the same: not requiring an http server